# Help with this riddle please

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> What can you take but not give?
>   What takes hours to do but it’s over in an instant?
>   You can get it but never save it.
>   What gives you sight without seeing?
>   Run without legs.
>   Travel the world but never leave.
>   The past is now. The future is history.
>   We all have been there.
>   It’s free.
>   You can do it with family and friends but they never see what you see.
>    Thousands of memories but no pictures.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 28):

I think the answer might be

> A nap/a rest!

What can you take but not give?

> Take a nap but not give a nap

What takes hours to do but it’s over in an instant.

> Hours long naps end in an instant when you wake up

You can get it but never save it.

> You can get to sleep but never save sleep for later

What gives you *sight* without seeing? Run without legs. Travel the world but never leave. The past is now. The future is history. We all have been there. It’s free. You can do it with family and friends but they never see what you see. Thousands of memories but no pictures.

> This all refers to dreaming when you sleep

Answer (score 4):

I think El-Guest answer is probably more correct but the first thing that came to mind for me was

> Time

What can you take but not give?

> You can take the time to do something but you can't give it

What takes hours to do but it’s over in an instant?

> I think the concept of time is that time seems to go fast for us (hours to do) but in the span of for e.g. the universe our lifetime is nothing

You can get it but never save it.

> You decide how to spend your time but once your time has run out it's over you can't save up time

What gives you sight without seeing?

> I think this refers to time being a concept that humans created we are the only ones aware of time.

Run without legs.

> time runs by, but has no legs.

Travel the world but never leave.

> Time for humans is a concept around the world but as stated before we are the only ones using it on our world.

The past is now. The future is history.

> not sure

We all have been there.

> we all exist in this timeline.

It’s free.

> time is free (unless your working :p )

You can do it with family and friends but they never see what you see.

> you can spend time with family and friends but they can spend it how they like.

Thousands of memories but no pictures.

> in one second of time going by millions of people have memories.

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

> A thought

My reasoning:

What can you take but not give?

> You can take a thought from something but you can’t give one.

What takes hours to do but it’s over in an instant?

> Following a train of thought until you reach an answer.

You can get it but never save it.

> Thoughts are ephemeral.

What gives you sight without seeing?

> Using your mind’s eye.

Run without legs.

> Projecting motion through thinking.

Travel the world but never leave.

> Thinking of places visited.

The past is now. The future is history.

> When you think you are recalling your previous memories to form new thoughts.

We all have been there.

> We all have the capacity to think.

It’s free.

> It’s free to think what you please.

You can do it with family and friends but they never see what you see.

> You can think with your family and friends but each person has their own thoughts.

Thousands of memories but no pictures.

> Thoughts project memories on your mind.

Answer (score -1):

Is it

> **DREAM**??

What can you take but not give?

> You cannot give

What takes hours to do but it’s over in an instant?

> 

You can get it but never save it.

> You cannot save dream

What gives you sight without seeing?
Run without legs.
Travel the world but never leave.

> true

The past is now. The future is history.

> ??

We all have been there.
It’s free.

> yes it is free

You can do it with family and friends but they never see what you see.

> true

Comment: @downvoter, but why?

Comment: It's likely because other people already used this answer and explained it better. Take a look at El-Guest's answer.